# substring in addplot table

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I want to add a figure which x label is symbols. But in data, the x label is longer than the figure's (because x label is abbreviated in figures). I want to know how to plot this kind of figure. The code is as follows. Thanks!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots, tikz}
\usepackage{stringstrings}
\begin{document}
\substring{abcdef}{1}{1}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
       symbolic x coords={a, b, c},
       xtick=data,
    ]
    \addplot table[x expr=\substring{\thisrowno{0}}{1}{1}, y index=1] {
      xx yy
      a1 1
      b1 2
      c1 3
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `x=xx` and `y=yy` in the options to `table`. Also use symbolic coordinates `a1,b1,c1` as they are in the first column. Change the tick labels using `xticklabels` key.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
       symbolic x coords={a1, b1, c1},
       xtick=data,
       xticklabels={a,b,c}
    ]
    \addplot table[x=xx, y= yy] {
      xx yy
      a1 1
      b1 2
      c1 3
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very thanks, but I just want to use a, b, c as x coordinates in figures. Because in my real data, "a1" may represent such a long string, e.g., thisisaveryverylongstring, that it cannot be convenient used in figures

Comment: @chunhui Please see the edit.